How to run rviz2 through VNC?
I am setting up a robot with Raspberry Pi 4 8GB RAM.
Wish to run ROS2 Humble on it without any monitor, then I can use any computer, just connect to it through VNC.
I installed Ubuntu Mate 22.04 and ROS2 Humble on the robot and when it is connected to monitor, everything including rviz2 is running without any problem.
However, when the monitor is disconnected, launching rviz2 through VNC will cause error:
[launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [rviz2-1]: process started with pid [3142]
[rviz2-1] qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 192, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20

Any setting can do on Ubuntu or VNC server to solve this problem?

I have not tried with VNC yet but I have tried it with XRDP and it works fine for me.

try installing the xvfb package, which allows you to run a head-less (aka monitor-less) X display.

@MichaelJonathan, I tried XRDP, rviz2 can on but the picture did not displayed properly...

@ChristianFritz, I installed xvfb, but not sure how to setup the display. Do you have any link as instruction to do so?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb#Usage_examples

I successfully make it with Ubuntu Server 22.04 + xfce4 + XRDP, will do more testing!
